# How to prove by induction the formula to find LCM of two numbers for multiple numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, least-common-multiple

There exist a formula to easily find the least common multiple of 2 integers:

$$
\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)=\frac {x\cdot y}{\gcd(x,y)}  
$$

And for multiple numbers:

$$
\operatorname{lcm}(a_1, a_2, \ldots ,a_n)=\frac {a_1\cdots a_n}{\gcd(a_1, a_2, \ldots ,a_n)}  
$$

I need help proving the latter by induction relying on the former formula.

Comment: Don't exist the gdc of >2 numbers

Comment: @vvnitram Sure it exists.  But the formula in the question is certainly wrong.

Comment: Counterexample lcm(5,2,4)=20 and "gdc" is 1

Comment: @ErickWong no, is two to two

Comment: @TheLogicGuy The denominator should be $\gcd(A/a_1,A/a_2,\ldots,A/a_n)$ where $A = a_1\cdots a_n$.

Comment: @vvnitram Are you confusing "exist" with "equals"?  What do you mean by "is two to two"??

Comment: $\text{lcm}(a,b)\gcd(a,b)=ab$ follows from $\text{lcm}(a,b)=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{\max\{\alpha_i,\beta_i\}}$ and $\text{gcd}(a,b)=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{\min\{\alpha_i,\beta_i\}}$.